# Is this a normal SSL error?

Tags: android, ssl, nginx

I am seeing lots of SSL handshake issues in my android App

```
E/AndroidRuntime(8853): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
E/AndroidRuntime(8853):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:390)
```

This is what I am seeing on the server side

```
SSL_do_handshake: -1       
SSL_get_error: 2     
reusable connection: 0   
post event 00000000013DA7A0
delete posted event 00000000013DA7A0
SSL handshake handler: 0
SSL_do_handshake: 1    
SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD"
reusable connection: 1
http wait request handler  
malloc: 000000000132A8E0:1024
SSL_read: -1
SSL_get_error: 2
free: 000000000132A8E0
post event 00000000013DA7A0
delete posted event 00000000013DA7A0
http wait request handler
malloc: 000000000132A8E0:1024
```

I am wondering if these issues are related and if someone went through this can give me some headstart on where to debug in Android and/or Nginx